# How to show large scrollbar in Kivy's RecycleView

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote the following code in Kivy in Python.

It is a GUI with only five buttons that can be scrolled.

I am running the following in an Anacond environment.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<TextWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'

        RecycleView:
            size_hint: 1.0,1.0

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: 5

                Button:
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'
                    text: 'TEST1'

                Button:
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'
                    text: 'TEST2'

                Button:
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'
                    text: 'TEST3'

                Button:
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'
                    text: 'TEST4'

                Button:
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'
                    text: 'TEST5'
""")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.properties import StringProperty 

class TextWidget(Widget):
    text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = 'test'

    def build(self):
        return TextWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

A scroll bar appears but is too small to touch.

[image]

So I have to scroll with the middle mouse wheel button.

Is there a way to display a large scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `bar_width` attribute:

```py
        RecycleView:
            size_hint: 1.0,1.0
            bar_width: dp(10)
            scroll_type: ["bars", "content"]
```